# VS2017 Linux compile, copy to remote linux changes file encoding

Tags: linux, ssh, visual-studio-2017

I am using VS2017 to compile a project on a remote LUmbutu Linux. But when vs2017 copies the source files to the remote Linux, its encoding is changed.

I am using strings like u8"Peça" in the source code, and when I examine the transfered file on the remote Linux machine, it´s no longer encoded as utf-8.

The character sequence for the string "peça" in the file is changed from: 0x70 0x65 0xc3 0xa7 0x61 
to: 0x70 0x65 0xe7 0x61

I suspect that this has to do with ssh copying of the file, but have not found any information about how this process is realized by vs in order to try diagnosing this problem.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Also see [Linux development with C++ in Visual Studio](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2017/04/11/linux-development-with-c-in-visual-studio/) on the MSDN blog. There may be a problem with Visual Studio copying the files. See the discussion in the comments. Also keep in mind, VC++ may not be able to handle C++14 and C++17 features at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

you trouble can be resolved easily, you make your files under windows, with cp1252 and when copying you do not have any conversion

you must save each file with utf-8 encoding!

you can do it under VS - Save-AS, on Save button press arrow down and choose save with encoding option

wbr
Fedor